# ld: framework not found Box

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, linker-errors

I'm getting this error every time when I try to compile the project.
This started happening after adding to pods "use_frameworks!" and updating to use :

```
#import <MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h>
```

Insted of:

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

for all frameworks.

There is no framework named "box" so I do not understand what this even refer to..

This error shows after all the project compiles, really at the end.

Did any one manage to fix this issue?

**Edit**

```
My podfile:

platform :ios, '8.0'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!
xcodeproj 'Stox'

pod 'FLEX', '~> 2.0', :configurations => ['Debug']

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.5'

pod 'DCIntrospect-ARC', '~> 0.0.4'

pod 'FiksuSDK', '~> 4.5.0'

pod 'Raven'

pod 'PKRevealController'

pod 'UIImage+BlurredFrame'

pod 'SDWebImage'

pod 'PEPhotoCropEditor'

pod 'Reachability'

pod 'HPGrowingTextView', '~> 1.0.1'

pod 'MBProgressHUD'

pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'

#pod 'UIActionSheet+Blocks'

pod 'AZSocketIO', '0.0.5'

pod 'TSMessages'

#pod 'ReactiveCocoa' , '~> 2.5.0'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '3.0'

pod 'NJKWebViewProgress'

pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 1.2.0'

pod 'Underscore.m'

pod 'Mantle', '~> 1.5'

pod 'RSKImageCropper'

pod "AFNetworking", "~> 1.3.4"

pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.10'

pod 'AHKActionSheet', '~> 0.5'

pod 'WYPopoverController', '~> 0.2.2'

pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 1.0'

pod 'SwipeView', '~> 1.3.2'

pod 'Masonry'

pod 'YLMoment', '~> 0.2.0'

pod 'YIInnerShadowView', '~> 1.1'

pod 'LinqToObjectiveC', '~> 2.0'

pod 'Typhoon'

pod 'CDRTranslucentSideBar'

pod "ZFDragableModalTransition"

pod 'LVDebounce'

pod 'AsyncDisplayKit', '~> 1.2'

pod 'PhotoTweaks', '~> 1.0.1'

pod 'Shimmer', '~> 1.0'

pod 'IHKeyboardAvoiding'

pod 'Parse', '~> 1.8.4'

pod 'DBPrivacyHelper'

pod 'AppsFlyer-SDK'

pod 'KLCPopup', '~> 1.0'

pod 'Vertigo'

pod 'iRate', '~> 1.11'

target 'StoxUITests' do
use_frameworks!
  pod 'Nocilla'
  pod 'OHHTTPStubs', '~> 4.3'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround to resolve this issue (Temporary fix :) )

1. Create a folder called "Box.framework" anywhere on your computer. Note the full path to this folder.
2. Create an empty file called "Box" inside of "Box.framework"
3. Click on your project and go to the "Build Settings" tab.
4. Find "Framework Search Paths" in your Build Settings (you can search for 
   "Framework Search Paths" in the search bar at the top)
5. Double click on the Framework Search Path and press the "+" button.
6. Add the path which points to the "Box.framework" folder that you created in step1.

Let me know if that resolves your issue.